# Receive an email when assigned a new TFS bug, task, or other work item

Tags: tfs, tfs-workitem

We are using TFS 2010 and Team Explorer's work item feature for Project Management.

When a work item (like a bug or task, etc) is assigned to a user, how can that person be sent an email informing them of the new item?

Comment: [This](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/track/alerts-and-notifications) Visual Studio documentation gives good insight on how to setup the e-mail alerts for yourself when an item gets assigned to anyone.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Try out the Power Tools. I believe the Power Tools allows you to manage some email functionality http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/bb980963. When I used TFS project management the Power Tools helped get me a bunch of stuff I needed. I think it would be in the Alert Explorer.

Answer (score 52):

After installing [TFS Power Tools](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/c255a1e4-04ba-4f68-8f4e-cd473d6b971f), you have to create a Custom Alert.

- In Team Explorer,Right click on Team Project Collection Root and select the Alerts Explorer.
- The Alerts Explorer opens. From the Alerts Explorer toolbar, click New. It will open the New Alert dialog.Expand the type of alert that you want to create to view the    selection of pre-built templates. Click the alert template that matches your notification requirements, or click [Blank Alert].
- In the Alert Definition section, rename the alert and define your custom expression. For example, you can modify the expression to receive an e-mail notification any time project director creates or updates work items or a Work Item is assigned to you.

[image]

Comment: What a great explanation with screenshot! Thank you, Jehan. (sorry I can't vote up your answer cause I haven't 15 rep yet.)

Comment: I set up a few alerts using this method but none of them seem to generate any emails.

Answer (score 6):

Jehan33 provided a great answer, but it doesn't address a common theme of a lot of people asking this question. The Alerts Explorer lets you set up alerts for a particular user, but not a generic notification that will apply to all users. I imagine it's common to want a global setting to notify the user that a work item is assigned to when someone other than himself alters the work item. If you want to do this, you have the option of using a plugin, either writing one yourself or there are a few on codeplex.

For example: http://teamalert.codeplex.com/

Also, writing a plugin of your own is not as bad as it sounds, and you can find some pretty good resources. You'd mostly likely want a plugin that subscribes to the WorkItemChangedEvent that would check who is changing the WorkItem and what they're changing to determine if you want to send a notification. At that point you can grab an email address from Active Directory and send your email if desired.

Comment: I agree with the teamalert on codeplex solution.

This post should help with the correct configuration for the teamAlert plugin.

http://teamalert.codeplex.com/discussions/355057#post893398

Answer (score 1):

For a long time, email alerts was the only option to learn about TFS changes.

Now, you can also consider using [CatLight status notifier](https://catlight.io).

It will show toast notifications directly on the desktop when a new work item matches the  query.

[image: Catlight work item notification]