# TFS, how to create customized alerts for work items

Tags: visual-studio-2010

Friends.

I have created a new test case work item as End date. Is it possible for me to create an alert when the end date becomes current date? Please help

Comment: You can check the thread here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5362122/tfs-team-explorer-work-item-e-mail-notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not really possible, because alerts in TFS are event based. This means you can only get notification mails using board tools, when the work item was changed. In addition to this, not all date fields can be compared if equal a value, most just allow to check for "Changes", "Changes From" or "Change To".

An alternative way would be a tool that is scheduled to run in the night, check the due dates and if equal today, then sent a mail. Unfortunately I have never seen a tool like this already published.

Answer (score -1):

Is not possible out of the box, but there is a TFS Extension which can accomplish this by allowing you to set some rules which if violated a new delayed workitem will be created and you can subscribe to be notified when a rule is violated , it can be set on any type of workitem, and you can set business rules on any field like due date or set the rule to escalate by example any task that is taking more than n number of hours/days.

Please check this :

[TFS SLA Server Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/0bac39ee-5ae3-45a6-bab9-6764595c7772)

[TFS SLA Client Extension](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/f1a00d4f-6c59-4774-b92d-b2fe0e66dc3b)